# Cannot uninstall ubuntu

Tags: boot-failure

I was given an hp with ubuntu already installed. I bought the system restore disk with winXP but Ubuntu will not read the disk. Infact. I can't even open the cdrom without using the emergency hole. There is power to the cd rom and the jumpers seem to be in place. I tried changing the boot order in the system settings to boot from the cdrom but it's not even listed as and option. can someone help me?

Comment: I hope you realize the laptop's inability to boot from CD has absolutely nothing to do with Ubuntu? If you can't see it in BIOS and the tray does not open means the drive is most likely dead. Now, normal OSes can be installed from a USB stick, but you want to break your computer by installing XP... :)

Answer (score 2):

Change in BIOS disk driver to IDE or AHCI and try.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your CD drive is broken.